# No module named 'django.db.backends.mysql.compiler'

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have this strange error since we upgrade from Django 1.11.5 to Django 2.1.3 (python 3.5.2). We use MySQL 5.7.24. The latest packages installed are:

- django-mysql==2.4.1
- mysqlclient==1.3.14

We also use Celery:

- celery==4.2.1
- django-celery-beat==1.3.0
- django-celery-results==1.0.4

The bug occurred only when we execute a celery task (`perform_display_ads_check`). It works if we ran the function without `.delay()`.

Here is code for this task:

```
@shared_task
def perform_display_ads_check():
    try:
        checker = DisplayAdsCheck()
        checker.check_all()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(str(e))
        message = 'Cannot check display ads. Reason: {}'.format(str(e))
        send_slack_message.delay(message=message)
        raise Reject(requeue=False)
```

`send_slack_message.delay(message=message)` works. There is no database involved for this one.

Here is the log:

```
    [2018-12-05 09:51:47,626: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task clients.tasks.display_ads_check.perform_display_ads_check[535c8b34-5cf4-48e0-a16d-a22b5979f38b] reject requeue=False: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tool/www/project/clients/tasks/display_ads_check.py", line 26, in perform_display_ads_check
    checker.check_all()
  File "/home/tool/www/project/clients/tasks/display_ads_check.py", line 38, in check_all
    clients = self.process()
  File "/home/tool/www/project/clients/tasks/display_ads_check.py", line 81, in process
    for client in clients_qs.iterator():
  File "/home/tool/.virtualenvs/tool_py3/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 50, in __iter__
  File "/home/tool/.virtualenvs/tool_py3/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 256, in get_compiler
  File "/home/tool/.virtualenvs/tool_py3/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/operations.py", line 316, in compiler
  File "/home/tool/.virtualenvs/tool_py3/lib64/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'django.db.backends.mysql.compiler'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tool/.virtualenvs/tool_py3/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 382, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tool/.virtualenvs/tool_py3/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 641, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tool/www/project/clients/tasks/display_ads_check.py", line 31, in perform_display_ads_check
    raise Reject(requeue=False)
celery.exceptions.Reject: (None, False)
```

Do you have any clues? Any tips? Please advise.

## UPDATE #1

We have noticed that it looks for the file in `dist-packages`, but there is no Django package inside of it. Django is in the `site-packages`.

## UPDATE #2

We finally found the problem. The solution was to recreate the virtual environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solved!

We finally found the problem. The solution was to recreate the virtual environment.